# Create NSDate for today at a particular hour and minute

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, date, time, nsdate

How can I create an `NSDate` with today's date and an hour, minutes, and seconds of 5, 0, and 0 respectively? I.e. the date will be 07/02/2010 05:00:00

Comment: It is easier to use NSCalendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//Gives us the current date
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setHour:5];
NSDate * date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
[gregorian release];
```

Something along those lines should do the trick.